# How to add content of file, as part of a terminal command

Tags: linux

I have the following command:

```
curl -X GET "localhost:9200/bank/_search?pretty" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{
  "query": { "match_all": {} },
  "sort": [
    { "account_number": "asc" }
  ],
  "from": 10,
  "size": 10
}
'
```

I'm trying to divide it into two parts, one part will be saved in a file.
so i can run something like this:

```
curl -X GET "localhost:9200/bank/_search?pretty" file.txt
```

How can i achieve this?

Comment: Isn't it possible to somehow concatenate text with text and run it as command?

Comment: Hmmm. I'm not sure I understand what you want to achieve, but you probably want a POST request, else you can't send data like that... Look at the --data option of curl, and in particular the possibility to use @ to read from a file.

Comment: I'm wondering if this question shouldn't more be on superuser ?

Comment: @VincentFourmond You can send a body with a GET request. It's only a convention that you shouldn't do it and it could open security vulnerabilities but e.g. for [Elastic](https://www.elastic.co/) it's the documented way to send a query and AFAIK it won't work with a POST request. [Here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-filter-context.html) is an example.

Comment: @ThomasSablik Ah, OK. Sounds a bit weird, though. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

To send data that comes from a file, rather than a command line argument, use `-d@file.txt`:

```
curl -X GET "localhost:9200/bank/_search?pretty" -d@file.txt
```

From the `curl(1)` manual page:

> If  you  start  the data with the letter `@`, the rest should be a
> file name to read the data from, or `-` if you want curl  to  read
> the  data  from  stdin.  Posting data from a file named 'foobar'
> would thus be done with `-d`, `--data` `@foobar`. When `-d`, `--data` is
> told  to  read  from a file like that, carriage returns and new‐
> lines will be stripped out.

For JSON, stripping line breaks like that fortunately doesn't matter.

Comment: Only the first part seems to work, it gives me the data, but then it says curl(6) could not resolve host filename

Comment: But `file.txt` contains header information and body parameters.

Comment: Oh, right. Then consider making it a shell script that wraps the entire `curl` command?

Answer (score 0):

You can read the file in place

```
curl -X GET "localhost:9200/bank/_search?pretty" $(cat file.txt)
```